# Segmenting audio in its different parts using deep learning

Tags: time-series, music, deep-learning, segmentation, clustering

I am trying to segment a song into its different parts. In pop music, it's common for a song to have a verse and a chorus. And they repeat. So it should be possible to use deep learning to find the segments in the song, no? Also it should be possible to categorize the similar segments into the same class (aka Bridge, Chorus, Verse etc). However I am lost when it comes to how to actually do this. Music is no spatial information, the temporal dimension is crucial. So I was thinking, maybe I need to consider it as a time series and preprocess it accordingly? My other thoughts are following: I have a spectrogram that I can get out of audio, or a waveform (like in the images). So is there a way to find the segments e.g. with clustering algorithms? Also, how do I then represent the data?
[image: waveform of my song, it's 3.2min long]
[image: The spectrogram, you can see some repeating patterns]
Any nudge towards the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How different is what you describe than [this](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~hengtzec/papers/iscas09_musicstructure.pdf) or even [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.12955)? Are you trying to specialise it to specific music styles?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of specializing on instrumental pop music. There is no source code for this right?